# Calling current perl script recursively and pushing result to array

Tags: perl, recursion

I have a perl script that takes 1 argument, stores the result in an array, after that goes to the element in the array and calls itself with the element of the array as argument and pushes the new result to the array. For some reason I can't get it to work and the array doesn't change.

I have something like:

```
#some code here that stores result in @result
foreach $i (@result){
    push(@result, `perl ./myperlscript.pl "$i"`);
}
```

How do I get this to work? And is there a way to recursively call myperlscript.pl better than this?

Comment: Sounds like a horrible hack. If its in the same script, why not use subroutines instead of calling itself via the shell?

Comment: I'm actually new to perl so I'm still experimenting with plain scripts. Of course if it's not possible I will have to write a subroutine.

Comment: You haven't actually shown us the parts of your script that populate the array and output the data, so there is no way to debug this problem.  (A script calling itself recursively, while amusing, is probably not the right solution to any problem.  I hope you are just doing this "because you can" and not for any real world application.  )

Comment: Please show the actual code. The example you have shown prints nothing to `stdout` so only an empty string will be pushed onto the stack.

Comment: A subroutine isn't a last resort. Recursively calling a script is probably the wrong solution to any problem

Comment: dan: yes I'm doing this only because I can
@Borodin after seeing how messy it can get, I agree. I will write a subroutine instead of this mess. Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to run the same script, you shouldn't write it like `\`perl ./myperlscript.pl "$i"\`` you should write it `\`$^X $0 "$i"\``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing a script that calls itself you *may* face a design problem. Try putting the main logic into a *subroutine* and call that. This gives you more control and is safer, as there is no shell escaping.

You also should not modify an array you are iterating over. This might be better:

```
my @tmp = ();
foreach my $i (@array) {
    push @tmp, function($i);
}
push @array, @tmp;
```

If you wan't to go in indefinitively, you should use the traditional `for` loop:

```
# infinite loop! Yay!
for (my $i = 0; $i < @array; $i++) {
    push @array, function($i);
}
```

If you can't rebuild you script and you have to keep it calling itself, you should rather *pipe* the arguments, than putting them on the same line. Benefits include infinite length of data, and increased safety (no shell escaping!). Just consider what could happen with malformed data like `x" | tee "mySecretFile`. And that is harmeless. But again, rather declare a subroutine instead of that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will write a subroutine instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Perl is not shell, and in general it's best to avoid the backtick operators and system() function, unless there's no other option, or you're knowingly doing a quick'n'dirty hack.

Learn to write a subroutine and do your recursion that way. You shouldn't be tackling recursion if you've not got the hang of subroutines.

---

However, let's discuss what you're doing anyway.

Your backtick invocation is OK:

```
`perl ./myperlscript.pl "$i"`
```

... and will return whatever that process puts to stdout. It follows that your program must print to standard out.

In Perl, adding items to the list being iterated *does* cause the iteration to continue.

```
push (@arr,10);
foreach $i (@arr) {
   print "$i\n";
   if($i > 0) {
      push(@arr,$i-1);
   }
}
```

... prints a countdown from 10 to 0. So there is potential for your code to work. However I think it's a confusing model, and not a good habit to get into. Modifying the data structure you're looping over is not generally considered good practice.

Your code showed no evidence of a stopping condition. When you recurse, you always need to consider stopping conditions.

Note that anything that happens to the @result array in a backtick invocation, has no effect on the @result array in the current process. They are invisible to one another.